# How can I restrict my moment js calendar to today's date?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How can I restrict my moment js calendar to today's date?

My concern is..

Calendar date must be clickable for last 1 year including today's date. Other dates must be fade out and made non-selectable.

Comment: Use maxdate:today may solve your isssue. better if you can share a working fiddle

Comment: thanks nishith!! it worked... i am developing in react js. So it was bit different than other invocations. Though i found a clue from your suggestion. Now i am invoking the moment datepicker component in this way...                             


<DatePicker
              minDate={moment("2014-09-07")}
              maxDate={moment()}
              selected={this.state.start_date}
              onChange={this.handleStartDateChange}/>